# Deny layered navigation to search engines

Tags: layered-navigation, performance

A common issue: enabling layered navigation on a shop with many products, will produce an exponential amount of unique URLs. Besides the issue with possible SEO penalties for duplicate content, this might invoke a DDoS attack on your server.

Example: my current client has only 10K SKU's, but over a 100K daily requests from Google and Bing.

So, how to deny layered navigation for crawlers and save precious recources for real visitors?

There seems to be multiple strategies:

1. Add filters to robots.txt, as described [here](http://www.magento.scommerce-mage.co.uk/top-10-things-to-remember-for-magento-seo.html) and [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4423/layered-navigation-seo)
2. The same, but configured in the webserver
3. Add nofollow and noindex in the template files as described in [this Byte blogpost](https://www.byte.nl/blog/reduce-magento-resources-using-meta-tag-robots/)

Are there more? Which is the best?

Comment: If they all work this question is a matter of opinion imho.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no SEO expert but what I've understood from someone who is a `robots.txt` allows for the URL to be indexed but the content to be hidden while a nofollow on a link prevents the whole URL to be indexed.

Again, I'm no SEO expert so if anyone can confirm it that would be great

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible

1) to hide layered navigation block from the output based on the user agents and filter our Google/Bing bots.

2) add a special variable in the url like "noind"  and then in the Google webmaster tools set to noindex such pages. See https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080550